# Why PHP code position (file upload) relative to HTML code matters?

Tags: php, html, position

**I am learning PHP**. **Can someone explain to me why this happens**, I am very confused and don't understand a tiny bit? I also **want to know** **the fundamental understanding of php code position and what it will case in result.** I have searched everywhere, there is no explanation. This is a question rather than a problem.Thanks in advance.

**HERE IS THE QUESTION:**

If I don’t add "if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") “ in php code, then the localhost web page is white empty.

If I put the whole php code before the "form", it works just fine.

If I put the whole php code after "form", then the localhost web page is white empty.

If I put the whole php code out of "/html", it works just fine.

Fine means everything works great. The localhost webpage shows the form, when I submit a file, it shows in the target file directory.

The Whole PHP Code (whiteout "if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")"):

```html
    <?php
        $f=$_FILES['ulf'];
        $fn=$f['name'];
        $ft=$f['tmp_name'];
        $td='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yuchengxu/learning/cs/code/php/uploads/';
        $tf=$td.$fn;
        if(isset($_FILES['ulf'])) {
        print_r($tf);
        move_uploaded_file($ft, $tf);
        }
      ?>
```

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php include "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yuchengxu/includes/head.php"; ?>
    <title>Upload File | PHP | Yucheng Xu (Xavier)</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Yucheng Xu (Xavier), a web developer. Visiting my website to get to know me.">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav_top">

    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="ulf">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">    
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <?php
        $f=$_FILES['ulf'];
        $fn=$f['name'];
        $ft=$f['tmp_name'];
        $td='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yuchengxu/learning/cs/code/php/uploads/';
        $tf=$td.$fn;
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          if(isset($_FILES['ulf'])) {
          print_r($tf);
          move_uploaded_file($ft, $tf);
          }
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I put the whole php code before the "<form>", it works just fine.

If I put the whole php code after the "<form>", then the localhost web page is white empty.

If I put the whole php code out of "</html>", it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few items:

1. PHP is server-side code. HTML is client-side code. The execution of server-side code happens before the code is sent to the client to be interpreted and displayed. Where your PHP code appears shouldn't have any effect on the client-side code.
2. Read up on [PHP POST file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)
3. Perhaps handle your file upload on a second page? This will separate the form logic from the upload logic, making it easier to debug what is happening.
4. Read up on [PHP error reporting levels](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks, your first answer "Where your PHP code appears shouldn't have any effect on the client-side code." solved my concern. After your assurance, I checked my original code again. It's kind of funny, actually it's just a typo, I typed an "s" after "print_r($tf);", which appeared to be like this "print_r($tf);s", and just like that made my whole webpage white empty.